# Are custom tracks cross platform in Hot Wheels Unleashed?

Tags: hot-wheels-unleashed

Are user created custom tracks available across different console platforms in Hot Wheels Unleashed? For example, if I create and upload a custom track on the Steam version, can my friend download and play my track on PS4?

Answer (score -1):

Simply because the game doesn’t have supported cross-platform play yet, I would assume no. However, depending on the way the data is set up, there may well be a server accessible from multiple platforms - but if you haven’t had success yet, I would consider it to be impossible  (or at least improbable) for the time being. Edit: However, though, if there is a way for you to download it as a file and give it to them, there may be a way to upload it directly to their PS4 and play it that way.